# Show a certain element in a component on scroll down and hide on scroll Up Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I was creating a button that will be visible when the user scrolls down and will get invisible if the user reaches the top.
I am using React hooks to track the scrolling but can't access up to which part the user has scrolled. I am using Html section of 100vh height each (3 sections) and a fixed header on top there is a **login/register** button which will be shown when the user scrolls down ie as soon as the user reaches 2nd section and will remain visible until the user reaches the 1st section ie root section. I have used  `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` is CSS of the main container

React Code goes here:

```
    import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
    import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

    import Header from './Header'
    import Sec1 from './Sec1'
    import Sec2 from './Sec2'
    import Sec3 from './Sec3'

    import './Home.css'
    function Home() {

        
        let history = useHistory();
        const loginregister = () => {
            //on click login move to login register page      
        }

        var mainConatiner = useRef(null)


        useEffect(() => {
            mainConatiner.current.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
              console.log("srolling");
            })
        })



        return (

            <div className="main-container" ref={mainConatiner}>
                <Header loginregister={loginregister} />
                <div className="middle">
                    {/* Root */}
                    <Sec1 loginregister={loginregister} />

                    {/* Bank */}
                    <Sec2 />

                    {/* Section 3*/}
                    <Sec3 />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default Home
```

CSS code goes here

```
    .main-container {
    background: #FFFCF5;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 0fr 1fr;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-padding-top: 10vh;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}
.header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 0.4fr;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
section {
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    padding-top: 15vh;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

***I want to get the section the user is viewing as on a single scroll the section changes. The `useEffect()` hook is called multiple times***

Comment: Take a look at the [react-intersection-observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer) package.

Comment: @ohlupo Thank you for the package name. I made this work by changing the threshold value.

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar thing with my project and I am going to show you how.

My idea was that I had a Chat window, and when user scrolls up to read previous messages, he can see a button to go back to bottom.

I had something like this in my ReactJS file that renders my div.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

class Chat extends Component{

  

  constructor(props){

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scroll : true,
      chatMessages : []
    }

  }


  componentDidMount(){
    if(this.state.scroll){
          this.scrollToBottom();
    }
    this.scrollToBottom(); //Initially scroll to the bottom of page.
  }
  scrollToBottom(){ //Scroll to the bottom of a div
    $('#chat_messages_container').scrollTop($('#chat_messages_container')[0].scrollHeight);
  }
  handleScroll(){ //Handle every scroll event
    let elem = $('#chat_messages_container');
    if(elem!=undefined){
      if((elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop()) > 1300){
        this.setState({
          scroll : false
        });
      }
      else{
        this.setState({
          scroll : true
        })
      }
    }
  }
 
  render(){
    let chatPoruke = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.chatMessages.length; i++) { //Getting messages
      var poruka_obj = this.state.chatMessages[i];
      chatPoruke.push(
        <ChatMessage props={poruka_obj} key={i}/>
      );
    }
    let scrollBackToBottom = "";
    if(!this.state.scroll){ //If false -> it renders the button for scroll to bottom
      scrollBackToBottom = <div id="scrollToBottom" onClick={()=>{this.scrollToBottom()}}><i className="fas fa-arrow-down"></i> Scroll Down <i className="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
    }

    return(
      <div id="chatdiv">

        <div id="chat_messages_container" onScroll={()=>{this.handleScroll()}}>
          {chatPoruke}

        </div>
        <div id="chat_bottom">
        {scrollBackToBottom}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Chat;
```

How it all works :
Inside return, you can see that I have a `chat_messages_container` div, which will contain all the messages one by one. I have added `onScroll` event to (whenever a user scrolls inside that div), it would trigger my `handleScroll()` function.

`handleScroll()` function decides if user has scrolled enough for my component to update its state.scroll to false, once it changes it to false, my button shows up.

Comment: Also my div chat_messages_container has fixed height therefore, once it is filled up, it will add scroll ability for me to use.

Comment: Thank you for this but I don't want to use Jquery.